# How to upload mail from locale folder *.eml to remote server

Tags: linux, email, command-line-interface

I need upload  my  mails in format "*eml" from  local folder to  gmail account using Linux terminal  .  For example some email :  myemail.eml file

Answer (score 1):

Try `mail` or `mailx` command.

```
mailx -s "subject line" recipent_email_id < /path/body.txt
```

Comment: I  try to upload mail like this "Your Order with .eml" for example

Comment: you want upload your mails to your own gmail a/c ?

Comment: Yes I would like upload my emls form my local folder to gmail account